# Hard congruence equation with large residual.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> So I want to explain how one would go about solving the equation
>
> $$y^{2019}\equiv 3571700849900719233 \quad (\text{mod} \ p),$$
>
> where $p=2^{64}+13,$ which is the first prime after $2^{64}.$

I asked this same question a few days ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3112779/congruence-equation-xa-equiv-b-textmod-p/3112819#3112819), but the answer does not adequtely elaborate for example how one would know that $2019$ is relatively prime to $p-1?$ (without using software that is) And why does $2019\; \alpha \equiv 1 \bmod (p-1) \implies y=3571700849900719233^\alpha \bmod p?$

Is there a way to algorithmically simplify the equation?

Comment: "how one would know that $gcd(2019,p-1)=1$?" This is easy. $2019=3\cdot 673$. Of course, $3$ does not divide $p-1=2^{64}+12$, since $3\nmid 2$. Similarly, with $673$. I think, Robert Isreal's answer is really clear.

Comment: As for the second question, it comes from raising both sides of the equation to the $\alpha$ power and applying Fermat's little theorem

Comment: I think it's unreasonable to expect to handle questions involving $3571700849900719233$ or $2^{64}+13$ without some computation.  $2^{64}+12$ is reasonably small as these things go...easy enough to check divisibly certainly.

Comment: The answer to the nontrivial part (2nd question) is already given in the answers in  the dupe link on your prior question (e.g. see my answer). Did you read them? If you did not understand them then you should ask questions there (in comments) before posting further (duplicate) questions.

Comment: @NathanielMayer To apply Ferma's don't I need the residual to be one? If $b=$ the big number, then doing what you say I get $$y^{2019\alpha}\equiv b^\alpha.$$ How is it applied here?

Comment: @BillDubuque - Yeah I truely apologize for the duplicate, but if you look at the comments in that thread, I did read, and ask a followup question but there was no answer. So my only hope was to wait.

Comment: But you didn't do as I suggest, i.e. ask questions in comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2385495/242) if the answers there are not clear. There is no sign that you read that thread (which answers your 2nd question). If everyone posted a new thread everytime an answer needed elaboration the site would be a big mess. Please *first* pose questions in comments. If that fails then post another question.

Comment: @BillDubuque - You're right, I totally missed this thread before. I'll have a look there. Is it ok if I delete this? Thanks for your feedback  on this!

Comment: @Parseval Fermat's little theorem says that $a^{p-1} \equiv 1\mod p$. Consequently if $n \equiv 1 \mod p-1$, then $a^n \equiv a \mod p$.

Comment: @Parseval That's fine, since there are no answers here (and it may save someone from posting another dupe answer). You can always pose another question if those answers (and elaboration) doesn't help.

Comment: @Parseval How did you miss it? That's the thread listed as the dupe target on your prior question.

Comment: @BillDubuque - Small screen, bad resolution and fast scrolling down to comments. That yellow bar statins its a dupe just flies up. Will be more careful next time and scroll slower.